# overlaying lat/lng gps coordinates on static google map using math (mercator)

Tags: google-maps, maps, geospatial, mercator

(without using  projection library)
I know the center point of my map, (-37.500,175.500).zoom (13) size. 400x400px, it's a mercator projection (standard google map).
It is used as a background image on a canvas 400x400px.
How do I work out the bounds of this map.

Answer (score 0):

assumes you order a map using centre coordinates,
    Zoom = 13 //google maps zoom level (1-18etc)
    screenwidth=400(pixels) //the width of the map
    Latctr = -37.450  //latitude of middle of map
    Longctr = 170.250 //longitude of middle of map
    1/ Lengthlat  = 111111 // length in meters of 1 degree of latitude
    2/ Lengthlong = cos lengthlat * 111111 //Length of 1 degree of longitude
    3/ Ratiolengths == lengthlat/lengthlong
    4/ LongitudeValueAdjust = ((lengthlat/(2^zoom)/(screenwidth*2)* RatioLengths
    5/ LatitudeValueAdjust = (lengthlat/(2^zoom)/(screenwidth*2)
    6/ Northwestlat = latctr + latitudeValueAdjust
    7/ Northwestlong = longctr -longValueAdjust
    8/ Southeastlat = latctr - LatValueAdjust
    9/ Southeastlong = longctr + longValueAdjust
    Now you know the coordinates of the corners of the map

```
Plotting lat lng to canvas/screen x,y  
//This is not a mercator projection, works fine for zooms > 9
Assumes 0,0 is the top left hand corner of the canvas  
lattodraw // Latitude value of the coordinate we wish to convert  
longtodraw // Longitude value of the coordinate we wish to convert  
1/Latplot = canavsheight /(southeastlat-northwestlat) * lattodraw-northwestlat  
2/Longplot = canvaswidth /(southeastlong-northwestlong) * longtodraw-northwestlong  
3/Draw pixel at latplot,longplot
```